# Assert string only contains letters

Tags: python, string

I have seen methods like `isAlpha()`, but it accepts spaces and punctuations, which I don't want. Any way to check that a string contains only big or upper case alphabet letters?

E.g. psudo:

```
"asdf".isLetters() -> true

"as df".isLetters() -> false
"as. df:".isLetters() -> false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> "asdf".isalpha()
True
>>> "as df".isalpha()
False
>>> "as. df:".isalpha()
False
```

According to the [documentation for `.isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) it does what it seems you're after:

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

To check for uppercase, use `my_str.isupper()`

Comment: `.isupper()` will check for upper case too

Comment: Thanks! Was some logical flow control error that got me fooled

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

if re.match(r"^[A-Za-z]*$", some_string):
    print "yey"!
```

Comment: Yup, and this can be easily modified to `re.match(r"^[A-Z]*$", some_string) to detect only upper case letters

Comment: @JackAidley It still seems that `s.isalpha() and s.isupper()` would be  more appropriate, and regex is sloww

Comment: True. But it's worth knowing about the more flexible solutions for their power to deal with more complex cases.